# (Vue/Nuxt 3) How to prevent existing components from being updated?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I currently have the following code in a Nuxt 3.5.2 (Vue 3.3.4) project:

pages/grid.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="grid-test">
    <div class="grid-test__panels">
      <GridItem class="grid-test__panel" v-for="panel in panels" :key="panel">
        {{ panel }}
      </GridItem>
    </div>
    <button @click="addPanel()">Add +</button>
    <button @click="removePanel()">Remove -</button>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.grid-test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<script setup lang="ts">
const panels = reactive(['panel-1', 'panel-2'])

const addPanel = () => panels.push(`panel-${panels.length + 1}`)
const removePanel = () => panels.pop()
</script>
```

components/GridItem.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('grid item mounted!')
  })

  onUpdated(() => {
    console.log('grid item updated!')
  })
</script>
```

When accessing the page, we have 2 "grid item mounted!", as expected:
[image: initial load]

But clicking in "Add +", 2 "grid item updated!" are shown in the console, instead of only a new "grid item mounted!":
[image: after clicking the add button]

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to skip the first two components from being updated when the third one is added?

It was also tested using Nuxt 3.5.1.